# different packets, union - is a correct usage\verify?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

documentaion have one simple example "serialization-unserialization" with one packet. (i not found more examples)

if i have a many structs of packet, i need use union to this? or this bad idea?

how i need verify income packets, before use it in program?

method Verify - all i need to validate packet? (struct is correct, fields are permissible)

```
include "body1.fbs";
include "body2.fbs";

union PacketBody {
   body1,
   body2
}

table Packet {
   body: PacketBody
}

root_type Packet;
```

```
auto request = Packet::GetPacket(&buf);
auto ver = new flatbuffers::Verifier(buf, len);
if(request->Verify(*ver) {
   //good ?
   auto body = request->body();
   auto body_type = request->body_type();
   map[body_type](body);
} else {
   //wrong packet
}
```

Comment: You do not need to repeat, as first paragraph, what was written on title

Comment: Repeating the title within the question is a valid, and I prefer it to seeing things like "the question in the title". However, The first paragraph should contain more than just the title; see the "Introduce the problem before you post any code" section of [ask]. (The title serves as an attention-grabbing summary, while the paragraph should explain the details.) If writing a fuller summary causes the question to be rephrased somewhat, so much the better.

Comment: sorry, i expanded my question

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `map[body_type](body)` (not sure what that's intended to do?) by something like `if (body_type == PacketBody_body1) { ... reinterpret_cast<const body1 *>(body) ... }`

Also, the verifier is for detecting data corruption, I wouldn't use it for testing if you have the right packet.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i expanded my question on the remarks on its formulation.

what u mean about "for testing"?
method verify check only struct, not fields for permissible? 
(and therefore  use map[body_type](body) is unsafe)?